# word count in spark-scala for rdd(String,String,Long)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word-count, bigdata

I am a new to Spark-scala, trying to solve simple word count(having multiple attributes as keys). can I get some inputs?
I have an Rdd(String,String,Long) like
(a,b,1)
(a,c,1)
(a,c,1)
(b,b,1)
(b,b,1)

desired result is an rdd like
(a,b,1)
(a,c,2)
(b,b,2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
rdd.map { 
  case (x, y, c) => ((x, y), c) 
}.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: @elisah: Thanks for the clearification: I always thought the other way because , i used it in my program and somehow it was processing it in a faster way ! 

def countByKey(): Map[K, Long] = self.withScope {
self.mapValues(_ => 1L).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect().toMap
}